How does one use CTEs in a stored procedure in Snowflake?
This very simple example fails in Snowflake:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example_procedure()
RETURNS TABLE (example_col STRING)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
  res resultset;
BEGIN
    WITH sample_cte AS (
        SELECT 'data' AS example_col
    )
    res := SELECT example_col FROM sample_cte;
    return table(res);
END;
$$; 

The error is confusing:
Syntax error: unexpected 'sample_cte'. (line 5)
syntax error line 5 at position 20 unexpected 'AS'. (line 5)

I'd really like to avoid building a query string and then execute immediate :query since it seems like this should work.

The CTE is part of the query. res := with sample_cte as (...) select example_col FROM sample_cte;?

As per Schwern's comment, the CTE is only have syntactic context just prior to a SELECT. So in snowflake you can put a CTE anyway you would put the word SELECT, and that includes nesting them.

So first WITH belongs to a SELECT:
with data(v) as (
   select * from values (1),(2),(3)
)
select v*10 as vv from data; 

the CTE data is defined as the first part of the SELECT block on the last row.
and gives:



VV




10


20


30



so the matching stored procedure, would put that whole block inside the paren of the res := ( ); line, thus:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example_procedure()
RETURNS TABLE (example_col number)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
  res resultset;
BEGIN
    res := (with data(v) as (select * from values (1),(2),(3)) select v*20 as vv from data);
    return table(res);
END;
$$; 

which gives:
call example_procedure();

haha, funny it shows the output column name EXAMPLE_COL for a split second and then pivots to VV, that is funny, and incorrect.



VV




20


40


60




try this, one way you can do is create a view with the CTE SQL statement and use the view in your procedure.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example_procedure()
RETURNS TABLE (example_col varchar2(1000))
LANGUAGE SQL
AS

DECLARE
  res resultset;
BEGIN

WITH sample_cte AS (
        SELECT 'data' AS example_col
    )SELECT example_col FROM sample_cte;

     res := (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) );
     
    
    return table(res);
    
END;

